# Unique time reachability for two symmetric ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

We consider the following ODE $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$ and $y'(t)=-f(t,y(t))$  with initial condition $y(0)=1$ and denote the solutions by $y^+$ and $y^-$ respectively.

Assume that f is strictly positive and the solution always exists. 
Let $T^-$ and $T^+$ be the unique positive constants such that $y^-(T^-)=0$ and $y^+(T^+)=1$.

My question is: Is $T^-=T^+$? .

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. No i didn't find any counter eaxmple.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $f$ is time periodic.

Comment: Did you mean $y^-(T^-)=0$ and $y^+(T^+)=1$?

Comment: Oh sorry yes I meant that

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $f$ is nice enough for the solution of the initial value problem to be unique, otherwise $y^+$ and $y^-$ aren't well-defined anyway.

It's true that $T^+=T^-$ if the system is autonomous, i.e., if $f(y)$ doesn't depend on $t$ explicitly. Indeed, given $y^+$ (and hence $T^+$), let $\tilde y(t) = y^+(T^+-t)$. Then $\tilde y$ satisfies the same ODE and initial condition as $y^-$, so by uniqueness they are equal:
$$
y^-(t) = \tilde y(t) = y^+(T^+-t)
.
$$
Hence $y^-(T^+)=y^+(0)=0$, so that $T^-=T^+$.

But it's false in general. Just consider the following scenario: For small $t>0$ the function $f(t,y)$ is very large near $y=0$ and almost zero near $y=1$. Then $y^+$ will increase quickly from zero to begin with, while $y^-$ will stay almost constant at $1$. Then, after the solution curves for $y^+$ and $y^-$ cross (say at some value $y=C$, which is just a little less than $1$) the function $f(t,y)$ becomes large for $y>C$ and small for $y<C$. Then $y^+$ will continue to increase quickly, and hit $1$ (at $t=T^+$) long before the slowly decreasing $y^-$ has made it down to zero.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying. I have some prove that even for nonautonomous case the two times are the same. If I consider the function $z(s)=X^-(T^--s)$, by taking the derevative we find that $z$ satisfies $z'(s)=-X^+(T^--s)$, by integrating both side we get $X^(T^-)=0$ which is by uniquness $T^+$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What's $X^{\pm}$? Is it a new name for $y^{\pm}$? Anyway, your computation makes no sense, since there's no mention of $f$ anywhere. If you look at my proof for the autonomous case, and try the same thing for the non-autonomous case, you find that $y = \tilde y$ satisfies $y'(t) = -f(T^+ - t, y(t))$, which is *not* in general the same as the ODE satisfied by $y=y^-$, namely $y' = f(t,y(t))$. So the argument breaks down there.

Comment: I see sir thanx. Bu I dee that my statement is correct if I assume that $f$ is strictely positive. What do you think?.

Comment: I don't know what "Bu I dee" is supposed to mean. Positivity of $f$ has been assumed all the time, since you wrote that in your question already. The statement is false in general, as I've explained.